# Алгоритм разложения числа на сумму степеней 2

Tags: математика, информатика, алгоритм

Подскажите, пжл, алгоритм. На входе может быть сумма любых степеней 2, максимальная 2^9 = 512, например:

1) 2 + 512 = 514

2) 1 + 16 + 32 = 49

3) 64 + 128 = 192

Answer (score 6, accepted):

По сути, степени двойки, из которых складывается число отражаются позициями единиц в его двоичном представлении. Например, число 123 в двоичной системе счисления выглядит так: 1111011. Единицы в позициях 0, 1, 3, 4, 5 (нумерация идёс справа налево, начинается с 0). Значит, 123 = 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^3 + 2^4 + 2^5 + 2^6 = 1 + 2 + 8 + 16 + 32 + 64. Про перевод чисел в двоичную СС написано много, я на этом останавливаться не буду.

Если побитовая арифметика для вас выглядит слишком сложной, то можно применить "жадный" алгоритм. Суть такова: на каждой итерации мы подбираем максимальную степень двойки, меньшую либо равную текущему числу. Запоминаем её как одно из слагаемых и отнимаем от числа. Повторяем до тех пор, пока число не станет равным 0.

Пример: разложим число 123.

1. Максимальная степень двойки, меньшая или равная 123 - 64. Запоминаем 64, отнимаем его от 123, получаем 59.
2. Максимальная степень двойки, меньшая или равная 59 - 32. Запоминаем 32, отнимаем его от 59, получаем 27.
3. Максимальная степень двойки, меньшая или равная 27 - 16. Запоминаем 16, отнимаем его от 27, получаем 11.
4. Максимальная степень двойки, меньшая или равная 11 - 8. Запоминаем 8, отнимаем его от 11, получаем 3.
5. Максимальная степень двойки, меньшая или равная 3 - 2. Запоминаем 2, отнимаем его от 11, получаем 1.
6. Максимальная степень двойки, меньшая или равная 1 - 1. Запоминаем 1, отнимаем его от 1, получаем 0.

Алгоритм закончил работу, в результате 123 = 64 + 32 + 16 + 8 + 2 + 1.

Answer (score 0):

Для решения поставленной задачи достаточно протестировать каждый из 10 битов числа. Самое простое - логическое И со сдвинутой единицей:

```
function bit_analysis($n){
    $bin_powers = array();
    for($bit = 0; $bit<10; $bit++){
        $bin_power = 1 << $bit;
        if($bin_power & $n) $bin_powers[$bit] = $bin_power;
    }
    return $bin_powers;     
}

$n = 514;
print("n=$n");
var_dump(bit_analysis($n));

$n = 49;
print("n=$n");
var_dump(bit_analysis($n));

$n = 192;
print("n=$n");
var_dump(bit_analysis($n));
```

Результаты:

```
n=514
array (size=2)
  1 => int 2
  9 => int 512
n=49
array (size=3)
  0 => int 1
  4 => int 16
  5 => int 32
n=192
array (size=2)
  6 => int 64
  7 => int 128
```

Ключи равны номеру соответствующего бита (или степени двойки, что то же самое).

Answer (score -1):

Начну:

1) проверяем число "a" на четность

1а) если четное a=b, переходим ко второму пункту

1б) если нечетное, то ряд начинаем с единицы,  получаем b=(a-1)  и идем дальше оперируя текущим числом b

2) число  b делим на 2 до тех пор пока не получим нечетное число, запоминаем количество делений i, возводим 2 в степень i, записываем это число z в нужный нам ряд,

3) b-z=c  и переходим к пункту 2

4) выстраиваем полученный ряд по возрастанию

Вроде так, могу ошибаться.

Comment: Недопонимаю немного. Набросал на бумажке, получилось так:
1) a = 1023
2) b = 1023 - 1 = 1022
3) 1022 / 2 = 511

И дальше не знаю как